# Place a point on a line, given only the two points (not the equation)

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Suppose I have this line,

[image]

but I do not know the equation to draw it. I only know that there are 2 points on this line : point 1 at `(1, 2)` and point 2 at `(2, 4)`.

I would like to know the best way to place a point on this line, for instance at `(1.5, 3)`, given only the coordinates of the two boundaries.

My goal is to place 2 points with this method so that I can draw a "subline" on this line : in practice, this is used to place windows on a wall, in a 3D tool. On this tool, I only get the coordinates of the angles of each wall, and nothing else.

For that, I already have implemented a working solution where I calculate the rotation of the line relative to the X axis, but it seems a bit overkill to me.

I also thought about calculating the formula of the wall so that I can easily place the points on it. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Would there be some other way of doing it ?

(Not that the walls are always straight, they do not curve)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: From two points, you can derive the equation for the line through them.

Comment: @MichaelBurr this too seems overkill (to me at least). Isn't there an easier way ?

Comment: Determine the line by determining the constants, $m,b$ in the expression $y = mx + b.$  Assume the points are $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2).$  Then, $m$ equals the slope which is $\displaystyle \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}.$  Then, once $m$ is computed, solve for $b = y_1 - mx_1.$  Then, you can draw the line, since you know it's y-intercept, $b$ and it's slope, $m$.

Comment: @user2661923 this one doesn't seem overkill, I'll try it, thank you !

Comment: Every point of line is given by $(x_1+(x_2-x_1)t;y_1+(y_2-y_1)t)$ with various $t\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu what does "t" represents ?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu ok I defined "t" as the distance in % from the first point, it works very well, thank you !